# Attempted Dark mode on a website won't change a specific button color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a Dark mode feature into a website I am making for an Assignment and it did work by making everything into a dark mode theme, but it is leaving one button (that is the same as two other buttons. Identically, line of code, name etc) and it just isn't allowing the color of that button to change

Button #1

```
 <div class="flex">
      <a href="#home" class="logo">Lincs Marigold Hotel & Spa</a>
      <a href="#availability" class="btn">check availability</a>
      <div id="menu-btn" class="fas fa-bars"></div>
   </div>
```

Button #2

```
<div class="box swiper-slide">
            <img src="images/home-img-1.jpg" alt="Luxurious bed to sleep in">
            <div class="flex">
               <h3>luxurious rooms</h3>
               <a href="#availability" class="btn">check availability</a>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Button #3

```
<div class="box swiper-slide">
            <img src="images/home-img-1.jpg" alt="Luxurious bed to sleep in">
            <div class="flex">
               <h3>luxurious rooms</h3>
               <a href="#availability" class="btn">check availability</a>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Darkmode JS file

```
const options = {
    bottom: '64px', // default: '32px'
    right: 'unset', // default: '32px'
    left: '32px', // default: 'unset'
    time: '0.5s', // default: '0.3s'
    mixColor: '#2B1103', // default: '#fff'
    backgroundColor: '#2B1103',  // default: '#fff'
    buttonColorDark: '#100f2c',  // default: '#100f2c'
    buttonColorLight: '#fff', // default: '#fff'
    saveInCookies: false, // default: true,
    label: '', // default: ''
    autoMatchOsTheme: true // default: true
  }

  const darkmode = new Darkmode(options);

  darkmode.showWidget();
```

Misc from script js file to accompany the dark mode

```
import Darkmode from 'darkmode-js';

new Darkmode().showWidget();
```

style css file for availability

```
.availability form .flex{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   gap: 1.5rem;
}

.availability form .flex .box{
   flex: 1 1 20rem;
}

.availability form .flex .box p{
   font-size: 2rem;
   color: var(--sub-color);
}

.availability form .flex .box .input{
   width: 100%;
   padding: 1rem 0;
   font-size: 1.8rem;
   background-color: var(--main-color);
   color: var(--white);
   border-bottom: var(--border);
   margin: 1rem 0;
}

.availability form .flex .box input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
   filter: invert(1);
}
```

Tried moving the button above the "div class swiper home-slider" and below the "section class home id home" and that changes it, but everything below the "section class home id home" bugs it out

Comment: The DOM inspector tool will show you exactly what CSS rules currently apply to an element on the page, and what CSS rules *don't* apply because they are overridden for some reason (specificity of selectors primarily).

Comment: The best way to do dark mode is to use CSS's `prefers-color-scheme: dark` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) this way your web page / website will respond to a users system preferences (rather than having to manually set on your page)